# $f_n$ the converge uniformly to $\sin (\frac{1}{z^2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Are there $f_n \in Hol(|z| < 1) \bigcap C(|z| \leq 1)$ that converge uniformly to $\sin(\frac{1}{z^2})$? You can use $\sin$'s Taylor series.

I plugged $\frac{1}{z^2}$ into sin's Taylor series and got: 
$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^0\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n + 1}}{(1 - 2n)!}
$$

According to what we saw in class, this sum should converge on the annulus $R_- < |z| < R_+$ where:
$$
R_+ = \lim_{n \to \infty} |C_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0
$$
$$
R_- = \limsup_{n \to -\infty} |C_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \infty
$$
What can I learn from these convergence radiuses? How can I continue from here?

Thanks!

Comment: The limit function of a (locally) uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous. That means the answer is ...